# Diagonalizing the matrix $A$, when $A^2$ is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

If the matrix $A^2$ is diagonalizable and $A$ is invertible, is $A$ diagonalizable? I know it is not true if we leave out the invertibility. For example 
if
$
A=      \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 1  \\
        0 & 0  \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$ (which is not diagonalizable), then 
$A^2=      
        \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 0  \\
        0 & 0  \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$ (and that is trivially diagonalizable).

But what if we require $A$ to be invertible? I believe in that case, answer to my original question is yes, but I'm not able to prove that. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Do you mean “diagonalizable in the complex numbers“ or are you only dealing with real matrices?

Comment: Try a 90° rotation!

Comment: @egreg it is over complex number

Comment: @TedShifrin I guess your comment assumes only real matrices, because in complex, I don't see anything special about 90° rotation matrix

Comment: OK. You should in the future make the underlying field explicit.

Comment: Sure, I'll try to do my best next time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming this is over the complex numbers.

Put $A$ in Jordan canonical form.  The square of a nontrivial Jordan block (with non-zero diagonal) is an upper triangular matrix with nonzero diagonal and above-diagonal elements, and the eigenvalue has geometric multiplicity $1$.  So if $A$ is invertible and not diagonalizable, neither is $A^2$.

Comment: Your assumption is correct. Thanks for the answer, but I still don't get it. I tried to do some research, but I'm probably missing some fundamental knowledge. I know what is Jordan canonical form and it is clear that square of nontrivial jordan block is upper triangular matrix. But I don't get rest of the answer. Eigenvalue of which matrix has geometric multiplicity 1? The one associated with the jordan block? And what's the role if the invertibility of $A$?

Comment: I consulted with my teacher and I understand now what you ment, thanks fir the effort.

Answer (score 1):

Notation: $E_{L}^{B}$ is the set of eigenvectors associated to $L$ for the matrix $B$.

As $A^2$ is diagonalizable, 
$$
E = \bigoplus_{l_i\neq 0} E_{l_i}^{A^2}
$$

On each $E_{l_i}^{A^2}$, $A^2 -l_i I =0 $ and then, as $l_i\neq 0$,
$$E_{l_i}^{A^2} = E_{-\sqrt{l_i}}^{A} \oplus E_{\sqrt{l_i}}^{A}$$
Hence $$
E = \bigoplus_{l_i\neq 0}  \left[E_{-\sqrt{l_i}}^{A} \oplus E_{\sqrt{l_i}}^{A}\right]
$$and $A$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't know why the second equation is true. Could you please explain where it comes from?

Comment: Because the polynomial X^2-L has two different roots, hence the restriction diagonalizable

Comment: Could you explain why do we need $l_i\neq 0$ below the direct sum signs? Would it be wrong to say: Let $l_1, \dots, l_d$ be distinct eigenvalues of $A^2$, then $$
E = \bigoplus_{i = 1}^d E_{l_i}^{A^2}
$$? And the same with the second direct sum.

Comment: $l \neq 0$ is required to write the second equation.

Answer (score 1):

Let me formulate what I believe is the precise condition to make this conclusion. No assumptions are made about the base field $K$ over which one wants to diagonalise

> **Proposition.** Let $A$ be a square matrix with entries in a field $K$. Assume that
>
> - $A^2$ is diagonalisable over$~K$, with eigenvalues in a set $S\subseteq K$, and
> - every element of $S$ has two distinct square roots in $K$.
>
> Then $A$ is diagonalisable over$~K$, with eigenvalues in $\sqrt S\overset{\rm def}=\{\,r\in K\mid r^2\in S\,\}$.

Note that $S$ need not be just the set of eigenvalues of $A^2$, and certainly $\sqrt S$ can be larger than the set of eigenvalues of$~A$. But one may, and we will, assume $S$ to be finite.

*Proof.* Let $P_1=\prod_{s\in S}(X-s)$, then by the first assumption $P_1[A^2]=0$. By the second assumption there exists for each $s\in S$ an element $r\in K$ such that $X^2-s=(X-r)(X+r)$, and $r\neq -r$. Choosing one such$~r$ and calling it $\sqrt s$, one has
$$
 P_2\overset{\rm def}=P_1[X^2]=\prod_{s\in S}(X-\sqrt s)(X+\sqrt s)=\prod_{r\in\sqrt S}(X-r).
$$
Then $P_2[A]=P_1[A^2]=0$, and since $P_2$ is split with *simple roots* (because of $r\neq-r$) in $\sqrt S\subseteq K$, it follows that $A$ is diagonalisable over$~K$, with eigenvalues in $\sqrt S$. $\square$

Note that in fields not of characteristic$~2$ the second condition excludes $0$ and any non-square from the set $S$ of allowed eigenvalues for$~A$, while for fields of characteristic$~2$ it excludes everything (i.e., the proposition will never apply). These are precisely the cases where the conclusion fails miserably.

Comment: Nice. I suppose you can do something similar with cubes and cube roots and more generally $n$th powers (when $n$ distinct $n$th roots exist for scalars in $S$).